# cxf-java2ws-plugin java2ws getting error org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException:

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cxf, java2wsdl

I am new to cxf, and getting this error when I run `mvn clean install -e` with Maven plugin cxf-java2ws-plugin.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <cxf.version>2.2.2</cxf.version>
    <spring.version>2.5.6</spring.version>
</properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- CXF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.schema</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.schema</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlschema</groupId>
      <artifactId>xmlschema-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
      <version>11.2.0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- XML -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSON -->
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.json</groupId>
         <artifactId>json</artifactId>
         <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

Below the stack trace:

```
    org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.getExtReg()Lorg/apache/ws/commons/schema/extensions/ExtensionRegistry; -> [Help 1]

    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-java2ws-plugin:2.2.2:java2ws (Administration) on project olis2_ws: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.getExtReg()Lorg/apache/ws/commons/schema/extensions/ExtensionRegistry;
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
        Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.getExtReg()Lorg/apache/ws/commons/schema/extensions/ExtensionRegistry;
            at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.Java2WSMojo.processJavaClass(Java2WSMojo.java:249)
            at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.Java2WSMojo.execute(Java2WSMojo.java:135)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
            ... 19 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.getExtReg()Lorg/apache/ws/commons/schema/extensions/ExtensionRegistry;
            at org.apache.cxf.common.xmlschema.SchemaCollection.<init>(SchemaCollection.java:82)
            at org.apache.cxf.common.xmlschema.SchemaCollection.<init>(SchemaCollection.java:77)
            at org.apache.cxf.service.model.ServiceInfo.<init>(ServiceInfo.java:45)
            at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:353)
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:523)
            at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:439)
            at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:195)
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:163)
            at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:100)
            at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractServiceFactory.createService(AbstractServiceFactory.java:39)
            at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.processor.JavaToWSDLProcessor.process(JavaToWSDLProcessor.java:128)
            at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWSContainer.processWSDL(JavaToWSContainer.java:101)
            at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWSContainer.execute(JavaToWSContainer.java:75)
            at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:83)
            at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:52)
            at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:39)
            at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWS.run(JavaToWS.java:76)
            at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.Java2WSMojo.processJavaClass(Java2WSMojo.java:246)
            ... 22 more
```

and my environment configuration are as below:
Apache Maven 3.0.4

Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\User\tools\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Can any one help me please?

Comment: First try a more recent CXF version. Latest release is 3.2.1.

Comment: Thanks @DennisKieselhorst, I have upgraded cxf to 3.0.1 and now I get this error: `org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-java2ws-plugin:3.0.1:java2ws (MyWebService) on project MyProject: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal `

Comment: Well you have a dependency conflict. Use mvn dependency:tree to find out. Why do you need jdom, dom4j, jaxen?

Comment: Hello @DennisKieselhorst, Actionally it was a conflict between cxf version, which I upgraded to 2.3.0, and maven version, also I deleted dom4j and jaxen. Thanks a lot, that solved the problem.